# FitNesse Trying to Run the Wrong Version of Java

Tags: java, fitnesse

I've just downloaded FitNesse and am trying to run it on Windows 8.1 with Java 1.8.0_101 installed.  The wiki runs up but when I click the Test button I get an error message:

> Could not complete testing: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\java"": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

There is no jre1.8.0_71 folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java, only a jre1.8.0_101 folder.  How do I configure FitNesse to point to the correct location?

I've had a look at the shortcut at C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe (where the java.exe file is actually the shortcut) and that points to the correct jre1.8.0_101 folder.  I found a blog post that suggested adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\ to the PATH environment variable.  That didn't work.  The Configuration File section under the FitNesse documentation seems to be able configuring tests and so-on, and doesn't seem to include how to configure the version of Java to use.  I'm stumped.

**EDIT:** This is what I get when I run up FitNesse from the command line:

> C:\ManuallyInstalledApplications\Fitnesse>java.exe
>   -version:"1.8.0_101" -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8090
>   Aug 18, 2016 11:22:23 PM fitnesse.ConfigurationParameter loadProperties INFO: 
>   No configuration file found (C:\ManuallyInstalledApplications\Fitnesse\plugins.properties)
>   Bootstrapping FitNesse, the fully integrated standalone wiki and
>   acceptance testing framework.
>   root page: fitnesse.wiki.fs.FileSystemPage at .\FitNesseRoot#latest
>   logger: none
>   authenticator: fitnesse.authentication.PromiscuousAuthenticator page
>   factory: fitnesse.html.template.PageFactory page theme: bootstrap
>   Starting FitNesse on port: 8090

Comment: How about providing the the complete path to your wanted Java.exe instead oft relying on path or other variables ?

Comment: Tried that.  It didn't make any difference.  Based on the command line output (which I've added to the question as an edit) it looks like it is running the correct version of Java to start with.  It's only when I click the Test button on the User Guide Two Minute Example wiki page that I get the error message.

Comment: take a look at your 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable maybe it is pointing to the older version

Comment: @tonakai: That did the trick!  I had to set JAVA_HOME in both the system variables and user variables for it to work.  If you'd like to add an answer along the same lines as your comment I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at your 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable maybe it is pointing to the older version

Comment: That did the trick.  I had to update both versions of the JAVA_HOME environmental variable: The system variable and the user variable.

Comment: cheers, not sure why you need to update both, i have set it only in user variable but  have windows 7 so there might be a difference...

Comment: Perhaps I didn't need to set both.  Tried the system variable first.  When that didn't work I updated the user variable.  It worked after that.  Even if I didn't need to update the system variable for the FitNesse test to run I think it was worth updating anyway, since it was pointing to a non-existent directory.